# C# WebBrowser Como posso obter innerHTML de um span dentro de uma div

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet, inner

***OI gente.***

Preciso obter com c# o innerHTML do primeiro elemento SPAN que tem um valor com numeros que está dentro de uma div e eu
já até escrevi um código que tá no caminho certo eu acho.. até agora é isso:

```
             HtmlElementCollection Elems;
              WebBrowser WebOC = webBrowser;
              Elems = WebOC.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

              foreach (HtmlElement elem in Elems) {

                  if ((elem.GetAttribute("id") == "MyId")) {


                  }         
              }
```

Pra fazer isso com o JavaScript eu consigo com esse código abaixo

**HTML**

```
<div id="myId" class=""><span>874.005.877-81</span><span class="clipboard-copy"></span></div>
```

**JAVASRIPT**

```
var x = document.getElementById("myId");
var val = x.querySelector("span").innerHTML;
alert(val);
```

Agradeço por qualquer solução para isso ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em um cenário perfeito, bastaria pegar pela sua id, e depois o primeiro elemento span após o documento ser carregado:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string html = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myId").GetElementsByTagName("span")[0].InnerHtml;
}
```

Mas há outros fatores que podem mudar isso:

A página não é completamente carregada no evento DocumentCompleted (utiliza ajax por exemplo).

Pode ou não ter o elemento com sua ID = myId. Deveria verificar a existência.

Pode ou não ter elementos `span` dentro do elemento selecionado. Deveria verificar se contém.